# Backbone:.js: How to find out who is deleting my model from my collection?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

My view is subscribed to my model's delete event. I'm seeing the model delete event being mysteriously triggered and can't find where/how that's being sent from my code. At runtime, I see the models being added to my collection, before being immediately deleted. How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: If your view is listening to the destroy event. Then give it a callback method it. Put a debug point inside the event and check the call stack. You can find it on the right side in Source Tab of developer tools when in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> If your view is listening to the destroy event. Then give it a callback method it. Put a debug point inside the event and check the call stack. You can find it on the right side in Source Tab of developer tools when in debug mode.